# Why pthread.h library is not exist in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum;
void *runner(void *param); /* threads call this function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_t tid; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of thread attributes */

    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }

    /* get the default attributes */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    /* create the thread */
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
    /* wait for the thread to exit */
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}

/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(void *param)
{
    int i, upper = atoi(param);
    sum = 0;

    for(i=1; i <= upper; i++) sum += i;

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

This is my code following book.
Make child thread and allocate the runner function to cumulative the values in array.
But **gcc Multithread_Pthread.c** isn't work and **gcc -pthread Multithread_Pthread.c** are also work not.
What is the reason and solution?

Oh I forget the result of each command.
Use the **gcc Multithread_Pthread.c** error has occurred.
Use the **gcc -pthread Multithread_Pthread.c** usage: a.out 
is the result.

Comment: What are the *full/exact* error messages? – Most probably it should be `gcc -lpthread ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ gcc  Multithread_Pthread.c -lpthread
```

Comment: I do this but the result is same...

Answer (score 2):

To complement Ren's answer: you should try to compile object files before linking them instead of building the whole program with a single command. Try this:

```
gcc -c Multithread_Pthread.c
```

This will correctly create a "Multithread_Pthread.o" object file, proving that "pthread.h" was found in system header files.

Next is command to try linking:

```
gcc Multithread_Pthread.o
```

You will get the same message error, proving you this is a linking error.

Comment: Second is error, first is same result...

Comment: @jake Don't launch second command if the first one fails. And what is the message error you get when you launch first command?

Comment: usage: a.out <integer value> is the result.

Comment: @jake this is not a compiling error. This is the result your program is showing when you launch it with no argument. Try launching `a.out 2000` instead of `a.out`.

Comment: Oh nono it isn't. There are no result.

Comment: @jake What do you believe `fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");` does?

Comment: I want to print printf("sum = %d\n", sum); this.

Comment: Oh sorry. I know why the "usage: a.out <integer value>\n" is printed. But I don't know why the "sum = %d\n" isn't printed and program is terminated.

Comment: @jake What is the instruction following `fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I know the program pass the 'return -1' then the program is terminated. I don't know why the program pass the  if(argc != 2).

Comment: @jake argc is the number of arguments in the command line including the name of the program itself. So do you realize why I told you to launch `a.out 2000`?